# Why is excel displaying my data as zero when I try to chart it?

Tags: excel, zero

I've been trying to make a chart comparing two sets of data from 40 countries, but every time I try to make the chart, it shows one data set perfectly normally and the other set is just displayed as zero.

I've tried changing from points to commas and everything else I can find online, but nothing is working.

I know absolutely nothing about coding, so please consider that when helping me out. I'm just trying to fix this for my maths assignment.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you select value corresponding to zero in graph and show us what is displayed in the formula field ("Fx")

Comment: It says =DATENREIHE(Tabelle1!$C$1;Tabelle1!$A$2:$A$41;Tabelle1!$C$2:$C$41;2)

Comment: Which translates as DATA SERIES according to google

Comment: So what do I need to do? I've tried hand-typing out the whole thing all over again as well now, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Have you formatted column C as numeric? Format cells  > number

Comment: Or plot a helper column which has for example C1*1, C2*1 etc in. If you get back an error message it means text in column C is not a valid number so cannot be converted.

Answer (score 1):

The other set is not displayed as zero! If you could use a ... microscope, you would notice that the orange dots are slightly above ground!

Each square in your diagram has a height of 0,5E15, which may also be written as the number 500.000.000.000.000 (5 followed by 14 zeros).

Imagine now that you want to place the dot that corresponds to the Albanian AAS number, which is 2.907.909,20. This is a minuscule number in relation to the height of each square. Excel thus naturally places that dot very close to the bottom of the first square, leading you to believe that it touches the horizontal zero line.

What you can do is the following:

Select with your mouse the line consisting of the orange points. Then right-click and select "Format Data Points" (or the German equivalent, I suppose "Formatieren Datapunkten"). Then search for "Series Options", where you will see the following two choices for "Plot Series On":

Choice 1: Primary Axis

Choice 2: Secondary Axis

Select the second choice and you problem will be resolved.

Viel Glück!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the excel's numeric formatting recognizes only commas (,). Press control, shift and key F at the same time. In the window that opens, replace all periods in the variable AAS with ",".

Your problem will be addressed